# calculate Hurst Exponent in excel

Tags: python, excel

i found this python code to calc the Hurst Exponent, given an array of numbers ts, but i'm having a hard time implementing this in excel (for mockup testing), just using worksheet functions (and eventually, C++ in Sierra Chart, which lacks some basic math transform functions like std and polyfit).

for excel, i think i can use the slope function in place of polyfit, and the rest of the functions (square root, standard dev) seem straightforward, but my brain is just having a hard time building the excel sheet.

Can one of you guys take a crack?  Maybe just convert into VBA?

*

```
from numpy import cumsum, log, polyfit, sqrt, std, subtract
def hurst(ts):
  # Returns the Hurst Exponent of the time series vector ts
  # Create the range of lag values
  lags = range(2, 100)

  # Calculate the array of the variances of the lagged differences
  tau = [sqrt(std(subtract(ts[lag:], ts[:-lag]))) for lag in lags]

  # Use a linear fit to estimate the Hurst Exponent
  poly = polyfit(log(lags), log(tau), 1)

  # Return the Hurst exponent from the polyfit output
  return poly[0]*2.0
```

*

Comment: Why not use VBA? In any event, Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service. Show your efforts and describe the difficulties you have encountered.

Comment: i'm struggling with the nested array functions.  for the "tau" line, can i break that up into 3 or 4 lines of code, 1 for each function?

Comment: how exactly would i convert this function into VBA ?